# Join with a table name stored in a variable in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If a `category` has many `posts` and a post belongs to a category, Rails can do the `join` as below:

```
Category.joins(:posts)
```

Our question is, if there is a variable table_name, and:

```
table_name = 'posts'
```

Can we do something like this(in pseudo code)?

```
Category.joins(table_name.to_sym)
```

Or this is not doable at all.

Comment: Yeah, that works fine. Check it in your console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes Rails can do the following and all of them are do-able.

```
Category.joins(:posts)

table_name = 'posts'

Category.joins(table_name.to_sym)

Category.joins('posts'.to_sym)
```

Comment: Do you happen to know if a table name stored in a variable table_name, how to access its field in rail query? ex, table_name.(:id)

Comment: you can access it's field query by giving the field name just like you typed in example